# What type to use for imported svg icon from an .svg file in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I have my `.svg` files in an `assets` folder and I import them like this:

```
import HeartIcon from 'assets/attributes/HeartIcon.svg';
```

Then, since I need to assign them to variables and then render icons conditionally, I have something like this:

```
const logos: LogosProps = {
  firstLogo: HeartIcon
  secondLogo: SomeOtherIcon
  thirdLogo: SomeDifferentIcon
}
```

When I want to render something from here, what I do is:

```
const Logo = logos.firstLogo

return <Logo className="some class name styles" />
```

And its all working just fine, I just cant figure out what the type should be for each logo:

```
interface LogosProps {
  firstLogo: React.FC 
  secondLogo: React.FC
  thirdLogo: React.FC
}
```

So what should I have in there as a type, instead of `React.FC`, I have tried `React.ReactElement`, `React.ReactNode`, `React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>` and a few others, but they all give me various errors, some give me an error that there is no constructor, others that I cant have className, and so on.

Right now with `React.FC` the error that I have is:

```
Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face the same issue before with `typescript`.

Create a file named `custom.d.ts` in `./src` with the following content:

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

Add the `custom.d.ts` to `tsconfig.json` as below
You will find this `tsconfig.json` file in your project root folder.

`"include": ["src/components", "src/custom.d.ts"]`

Source: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/#importing-other-assets

Hope this will resolve your issue.